# org.json.JSONException: No value for id - IMPOSSIBLE TO SOLVE

Tags: java, android, json, websocket

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-2/

Hi,

This is a tutorial about building a group chat app using socket programming. This app allows us to chat between multiple devices like android mobiles and web.

I want to send more than one "String" at a time to the server. I'm having trouble figuring that out.

The link to the tutorial where I downloaded the code is pasted above. I've already made the dynamic web page and I have it hosted on eapps.com At the very bottom of the this email is the edited code for the app. If you click the link above, you can see how I changed it.

The way it works is..

> A web socket is created using WebSocketClient class and it has all the callback methods like onConnect, onMessage and onDisconnect.
>   In onMessage method parseMessage() is called to parse the JSON received from the socket server.
>   In parseMessage() method, the purpose of JSON is identified by reading the flag value.
>   When a new message is received, the message is added to list view data source and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is called to update the chat list.
>   sendMessageToServer() method is used to send the message from android device to socket server.
>   playBeep() method is called to play device’s default notification sound whenever a new message is received.​

When you click the btnSend. it uses this method from the UtilsXd class. I've changed it a little in an attempt to pass an extra value.

```
public String getSendMessageJSONXD(String message, String whichPicIndex) {
        String json = null;

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
            jObj.put("flag", FLAG_MESSAGE);
            jObj.put("sessionId", getSessionId());
            jObj.put("message", message);
            jObj.put("id", id);
            json = jObj.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }
```

First of all, what I still don't understand is, where did the values for

```
String sessionId = jObj.getString("sessionId");
```

and

```
String onlineCount = jObj.getString("onlineCount");​
```

from this method

```
private void parseMessage(final String msg, String idINDEX) {
```

come from.

They were't added in the JSON object created in the UtilsXD class so how are they created?

That's not the problem I'm having. This is.

superString is the value I want to pass to dictate which picture to show.

```
superString = (sharedPrefs.getString("prefSyncAvatar", "1"));​
```

You can change your picture in from the settings.

When a message is received, a switch/case statement changes the picture of/ for the message received according to the value passed by superString.

I should be able to sit there and just receive messages, and whatever number the user passes, the profilePicture should be set according to that number.

Here's where the problem begins.

This constructer builds a message based of the message that's just been parsed.

```
// Message m = new Message(fromName, message, isSelf);
                Message m = new Message(fromName, message, isSelf, id, name,
                        image, status, profilePic, timeStamp, url);
```

In this method.

```
private void parseMessage(final String msg, String idINDEX) {
```

I can pass an value to the string "id" excluding the JSON I need it to.

```
String id = idINDEX;​
```

this works,

```
String id = "0";
```

this works,

```
String id = utils.getPictureId();
```

this works,

```
String id = jObj.getString("id");
```

This doesn't work.

This is the error I'm getting.

org.json.JSONException: No value for id (this is the issue)

I've added the key/value pair

```
jObj.put("id", id);
```

in

```
public String getSendMessageJSONXD(String message, String whichPicIndex) {​
```

but it's not coming though to the message.

Here's where I think the problem is.

The method onMessage, isn't can't take an extra parameter because it's from a library project. And I can't find that method to make a new constructor.

```
@Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got string message! %s", message));

                parseMessage(message, superString);


            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(byte[] data) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got binary message! %s",
                        bytesToHex(data)));
                String hello = "99";

                parseMessage(bytesToHex(data), superString);


            }
```

/////// Here's the final code below ////////

```
    // JSON flags to identify the kind of JSON response
        private static final String TAG_SELF = "self", TAG_NEW = "new",
                TAG_MESSAGE = "message", TAG_ID = "id", TAG_EXIT = "exit";



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "CutPasteId" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_chat);

        showUserSettings();
        getActionBar().setTitle("City Chat - Beta 1.3");

        superString = (sharedPrefs.getString("prefSyncAvatar", "1"));

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_messages);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        // We first check for cached request

        vollewStuff();
        //
        //
        // THis is where this fun begins

        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        inputMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMsg);
        listViewMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_messages);

        utils = new UtilsXD(getApplicationContext());

        // Getting the person name from previous screen
        Intent i = getIntent();
        name = i.getStringExtra("name");



        Integer.parseInt((sharedPrefs.getString("prefSyncAvatar", "1")));

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Sending message to web socket server
                sendMessageToServer(utils.getSendMessageJSONXD(inputMsg
                        .getText().toString(), superString), superString);

                utils.storePictureId((sharedPrefs.getString("prefSyncAvatar",

                "1")));

                // Clearing the input filed once message was sent
                inputMsg.setText("");
            }
        });

        listMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();

        adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(this, listMessages, feedItems);
        listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Creating web socket client. This will have callback methods
         * */
        client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create(WsConfig.URL_WEBSOCKET
                + URLEncoder.encode(name)), new WebSocketClient.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect() {

            }

            /**
             * On receiving the message from web socket server
             * */
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got string message! %s", message));

                parseMessage(message, superString);

                // parseMessage(message,
                // (sharedPrefs.getString("prefSyncAvatar", "1")));

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(byte[] data) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got binary message! %s",
                        bytesToHex(data)));
                String hello = "99";

                parseMessage(bytesToHex(data), superString);

                // Message will be in JSON format
                // parseMessage(bytesToHex(data),
                // (sharedPrefs.getString("prefSyncAvatar", "1")));
            }

            /**
             * Called when the connection is terminated
             * */
            @Override
            public void onDisconnect(int code, String reason) {

                String message = String.format(Locale.US,
                        "Disconnected! Code: %d Reason: %s", code, reason);

                showToast(message);
                //
                // clear the session id from shared preferences
                utils.storeSessionId(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error! : " + error);

                // showToast("Error! : " + error);

                showToast("Are you sure you want to leave?");
            }

        }, null);

        client.connect();
    }


    /**
     * Method to send message to web socket server
     * */

    private void sendMessageToServer(String message, String id) {
        if (client != null && client.isConnected()) {
            client.send(message);
            client.send(id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parsing the JSON message received from server The intent of message will
     * be identified by JSON node 'flag'. flag = self, message belongs to the
     * person. flag = new, a new person joined the conversation. flag = message,
     * a new message received from server. flag = exit, somebody left the
     * conversation.
     * */

    private void parseMessage(final String msg, String idINDEX) {

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(msg);

            // JSON node 'flag'
            String flag = jObj.getString("flag");

            String id = idINDEX;

            // if flag is 'self', this JSON contains session id
            if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_SELF)) {

                String sessionId = jObj.getString("sessionId");

                // Save the session id in shared preferences
                utils.storeSessionId(sessionId);

                Log.e(TAG, "Your session id: " + utils.getSessionId());

            } else if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_NEW)) {
                // If the flag is 'new', new person joined the room
                String name = jObj.getString("name");
                String message = jObj.getString("message");

                // number of people online
                String onlineCount = jObj.getString("onlineCount");

                showToast(name + message + ". Currently " + onlineCount
                        + " people online!");

            } else if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_MESSAGE)) {
                // if the flag is 'message', new message received
                String fromName = name;
                String message = jObj.getString("message");
                String sessionId = jObj.getString("sessionId");

                // switch (Integer.parseInt((sharedPrefs.getString(
                // "prefSyncAvatar", "1"))))

                boolean isSelf = true;

                switch (Integer.parseInt(utils.getPictureId())) {

                case 1:

                    profilePic = "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatlion.png";

                    break;
                case 2:

                    profilePic = "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatmatt.png";

                    break;
                case 3:

                    profilePic = "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatroboman.png";

                    break;
                case 4:

                    profilePic = "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatalien.png";

                    break;
                case 5:

                    profilePic = "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatkitty.png";

                    break;

                case 10:

                    profilePic = "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatkitty.png";

                    break;

                }

                // Checking if the message was sent by you
                if (!sessionId.equals(utils.getSessionId())) {
                    fromName = jObj.getString("name");
                    // profilePic = jObj.getString("profilePic");

                    //
                    //
                    //
                    //
                    jObj.getString("message");
                    isSelf = false;

                    profilePic = "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatalien.png";
                }

                // profilePic =
                // "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/citychatlion.png";

                Integer.parseInt(utils.getPictureId());

                String name = "clxxxii";
                String image = "http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1716876/thumbs/o-ATLANTA-TRAFFIC-facebook.jpg";
                String status = "status";
                String timeStamp = "1403375851930";
                String url = "url";

                // Message m = new Message(fromName, message, isSelf);
                Message m = new Message(fromName, message, isSelf, id, name,
                        image, status, profilePic, timeStamp, url);

                // Appending the message to chat list
                appendMessage(m);

            } else if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_EXIT)) {
                // If the flag is 'exit', somebody left the conversation
                String name = jObj.getString("name");
                String message = jObj.getString("message");

                showToast(name + message);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

///////// I've updated the socket server from the first project. /////// I've added the JSON value "id" successfully /// But I how do I change the value without having to type in "5" please see below..

//
This is the JSONutilty method I changed.
//
    public String getSendAllMessageJson(String sessionId, String fromName,
                String message, String photoId) {
            String json = null;

```
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
            jObj.put("flag", FLAG_MESSAGE);
            jObj.put("sessionId", sessionId);
            jObj.put("name", fromName);
            jObj.put("message", message);
            jObj.put("id", photoId);

            json = jObj.toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

This is the method that is being used by SocketServer. I can successfully send a message from this activity, to the utility method to send over the network.

```
                // Normal chat conversation message
                json = jsonUtils //
                        .getSendAllMessageJson(sessionId, name, message, "5");
```

How can I retrieve a value sent over the network to place in spot where I have "5" instead of hard coding it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: No value for id means that your jsonobject dosen't contain id value, so check your json.

Answer (score 2):

`jobj` doesn't have the value `id`. Example of the JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "message": " joined conversation!",
    "flag": "new",
    "sessionId": "4",
    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
    "onlineCount": 6
}
```

(as shown in the [part1](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/) of the same tutorial).

That solves the first issue of `onlineCount` and `sessionId`.

Comment: I can't edit the JSON file in the web server because won't that mess the the way the app connects to the server.

Comment: So, I couldn't check the entire tutorial, but you know that you need to complete the entire `part1` in order to be able to use app from `part2`, right? Because, it seems that the `part1` creates the server-client architecture you use in your `part2` and also, the `part1` seems to create the look of the `JSON Object`. So, you will probably need to change a bunch of stuff in the `part1` before you are able to change how you get messages `getSendMessageJSON` in your `part2`. For example, you should try starting from changing `getNewClientJson` from `part1` and see how it goes.

Comment: I will try to check the tutorial if I have time, and report back if you still have any issues... :)

Comment: public class WsConfig {
 public static final String URL_WEBSOCKET = "ws://68.169.50.115:8080/clxxxii/chat?name=";
}   I've done the tutorial.. I've mad the web app..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @miselking, you where correct, The server was missing the JSON string "id". To actually solve the problem of post.

"I want to send more than one "String" at a time to the server. I'm having trouble figuring that out."

This is how you do it.

Step 1)

Adding the string photoId to the method

```
public String getSendAllMessageJson(String sessionId, String fromName,
            String message, String photoId) {
        String json = null;

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
            jObj.put("flag", FLAG_MESSAGE);
            jObj.put("sessionId", sessionId);
            jObj.put("name", fromName);
            jObj.put("message", message);
            jObj.put("id", photoId);

            json = jObj.toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

Step 2)

Add the string to the correct sting to the method.

```
  String json = null;
  json = jsonUtils 
  .getSendAllMessageJson(sessionId, name, message,
                                    photoId);
```

Step 3) Parse the JSON

```
    try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(message);
            msg = jObj.getString("message");
            photoId = jObj.getString("id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```